# How to run a symfony project without having this folder structure

Tags: symfony

whenever i try to run my project i get the folder structure only.Why?

Index of /my_project

```
Parent Directory             
README.md
bin/ 
composer.json        
composer.lock   
vendor/  
web/
```

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: here,  index.php is not running directly

Comment: Is it a Symfony project as the tag implies?  If so you need to determine what happened to the app and src directories.  It is also very unclear as to how "run my project" would result in a directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your **.htaccess** or **httpd.conf** to access the web folder

**Solution #1:**

Create a **.htaccess** file with the following file-contents in the **DocumentRoot** folder (basically the place where you see this folder structure)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  RewriteBase /web

  # we skip all files with .something
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ app.php [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

**Solution #2:**

You can also adjust the **httpd.conf** depending on your web-hosting provider, if that's the case I would consult this page on symfony: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

**Update:**
Please mark this question as answered if it answered your question